# is it possible to make a zigzag form with curve using the whole line?

Tags: modeling, path

I want to make a zig-zag using the curve path. I have been trying the ways that I know to edit the curve as alt+s and ctrl+t and I played with the options at the right but it might not be possible. does anyone know? I need to know if I might be wasting energy and time or if it is possible. And if anyone has a better idea to make this "belt" that has a zig-zag in between two lines... the belt belongs to Zelda btw... :D ...I wanted to add more images here but I can't either because of my level or because I should not ...be patient with me

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can e.g. use geometry nodes:

1. double your curve
2. use this gn tree:

[image]

3. object -> convert to mesh
4. object -> convert to curve

then you have what you want.

By changing the integer input you can change the number of points:

[image]

Note 1: if you connect the join geometry with the group output, you can see both, your curve + the zig zag.

By changing the scale value, you can change the zig zag height:

[image]

Comment: A million thanks @Chris :) , may I ask... how can you add more than 3 pictures and even gifs? is it because of your reputation?

Comment: possible - i know there are some things you cannot do with too less reputation, i think there is even a site which explains that - but i don't know that by heart, sorry. But your question was asked i a good way and easy understandable - so that one image was enough - in my opinion.